# How we can use ng-keypress in a div?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use `ng-keypress` for a `div`. But the following is not working:

**Html**:

```
<div ng-keypress="myFunction($event)></div>.
```

**Javascript**:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(keyEvent) {
  if (keyEvent.which === 13)
    alert('I am an alert');
}
```

Comment: You generally can't focus a div so it wouldn't make sense to keypress in a div

Comment: I would imagine adding `contenteditable="true"` would make this work for you. I'd recommend fixing your markup as well with a closing `"`

Comment: I have a jquery code, in which keypress is working for div.But now i want to change my code in angular.

Comment: <script>
    var app = angular.module("switchExample", []);
    app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var r = 100;
        var t = 100;
        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 37) {
                $('#plane').removeClass('fa-rotate-90');
                $('#plane').removeClass('fa-rotate-270');
                $('#plane').addClass('fa-rotate-180');
            }
        });
    }]);
</script>

Comment: <body ng-app="switchExample">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <div class="container well">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="mainArea">
                        <div id="plane" class="myclass"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-space-shuttle"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: @MMorris write your code in question rather than in comments.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i know tabindex makes it focusable and therefore allows the keypress event to be triggered but the specific ng-keypress is never run.

Answer (score 2):

Try add tabindex="1" for that div. hope it work

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long time, but I have no issue getting a key press on a `div`. Provided the `div` has focus. Its the `tabindex="0"` attribute that allows it to receive focus and thus key press events.

In this example, you must first click on (or tab to if you want) the `div` before keys are received. You could easily do this programatically in your code.

example code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
    <style>
      .box {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">    
    <div class="box" ng-keypress="key($event)" tabindex="0"></div>
  </body>
  <script>    
    angular
      .module('app', [])
      .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

        $scope.key = ($event) => {
          console.log('got key ' + $event.code);
        }
      }]);
    </script>
</html>
```

You don't get all keys with `ng-keypress` (e.g arrow keys), but if you use `ng-keydown` you do get those keys too.